# JsonPropertyAttribute Cancels DisplayAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I have a models class library that defines DTOs used for both JSON serialization in WebAPI as well as model transport in ASP.NET MVC. Because they are the models for both functions I have my models classes decorated with DisplayAttribute and JsonPropertyAttribute (Newtonsoft.Json) to give both a human-readable label as well as a completely different serialized property name. What I'm finding is that the class properties decorated with both attributes lose their label and instead display the property name (e.g., "CompanyCode" instead of "Company Code"). Is there a known compatibility issue between DisplayAttribute and JsonPropertyAttribute that would cause this? Perhaps an order-of-precedence that isn't clearly documented?

I'd really prefer not to duplicate my classes in the MVC project just to whittle the attribute decorations down to one. I hate duplicate code. Here's an example of the issue:

```
public class Store {
    // This one doesn't work in Razor:
    [Display(Name = "Company Code")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "company_code")]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    // This one works in Razor without the JsonPropertyAttribute:
    [Display(Name = "Store Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Razor view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Store

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

The WebAPI controller method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetStore(string companyCode) {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new MyProject.Models.Store {
        CompanyCode = companyCode,
        Name = "New Store"
    });
}
```

**UPDATE** Because of inconsistent behavior with these two attributes and my inability to make it work, I've decided to make a dedicated ViewModel class with conversion methods. For information's sake, here's the new code:

```
public sealed class Store {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "company_code")]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class StoreModel {
    [DisplayName("Company Code")]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static StoreModel FromStore(Store store) {
        return new StoreModel {
            CompanyCode = store.CompanyCode,
            Name = store.Name
        };
    }

    public Store ToStore() {
        return new Store {
            CompanyCode = CompanyCode,
            Name = Name
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: As an update, the combination of DisplayAttribute and JsonPropertyAttribute have no adverse effect on `@Html.DisplayNameFor` and the specified display name shows properly. However, because only the `<label>` tag makes an accessible Web site I'd rather not use `@Html.DisplayNameFor` if I can help it.

Comment: Update to my update: it appears that even DisplayNameFor is internally inconsistent in this scenario. Some of my properties decorated with a DisplayNameAttribute show the proper human-readable text while others arbitrarily do not. Without consistency even in failures I can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change the attribute Display to DisplayName:

```
[DisplayName("Company Code")]
```

My complete code:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = new User()
        {
            Id = 1, Name = "Julio", LastName = "Avellaneda"
        };

        return View("Index", user);
    }
}

public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new User
        {
            Id = 1, Name = "Julio", LastName = "Avellaneda"
        });
    }
}
```

If I test in fiddler the web api endpoint:

[image]

And my View:

[image]
Regards,

Comment: That didn't do it, unfortunately. It really appears as though the combination of Display(Anything) and JsonProperty cause some kind of problem, though I can't find any documentation that states it directly.

Comment: Hi friend, I updated my answer to put all the code that for me is working, please check it!

Comment: Thank you so much for posting that. It's puzzling me that it works for you but even still not for me. If I comment out the JsonProperty attribute, it works like magic. My problem is that I can't just comment out the JsonProperty attributes because I need them on my models for WebAPI. There's obviously some kind of conflict happening somewhere that I can't debug.

Comment: Ummm so strange, well, maybe, if you can share me some example project to reproduce the error to see if I found any more.

Comment: I've decided to just go a different route and make a dedicated ViewModel with conversion methods. I've spent too much time on this already and have to get it finished up. I'm marking your answer because technically everything should work as you've stated. Thanks so much for your help!